# How can I return the total count of distinct column values for each month in current year, the months should return as column headers

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by, pivot

I am trying to query a table to return the total count of distinct users on a project for each month on the current year.  The query I have works, except it returns 2 rows, one that has a total count of users for each project each month (which counted duplicate users, which I do NOT want).  The second row is exactly what I want.

How can I fix my query to return just the second row of data?

Below I have a sample table and the query I have come up with:

```
CREATE TABLE [table_emp]
    ([Username] varchar(8), [Project] varchar(8), [Hours] int, [DateInfo] date);

INSERT INTO [table_emp]
    ([Username], [Project], [DateInfo])
VALUES
    ('userA', 'ProjectA', 5, '2019-03-19 00:00:00'),
    ('userA', 'ProjectA', 5, '2019-03-07 00:00:00'),
    ('userB', 'ProjectA', 5, '2019-03-07 00:00:00'),
    ('userB', 'ProjectB', 2, '2019-11-12 00:00:00'),
    ('userB', 'ProjectC', 1, '2019-11-12 00:00:00');
```

```
SELECT 
  SUM(CASE datepart(month,DateInfo) WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'January',
  SUM(CASE datepart(month,DateInfo) WHEN 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 

'February',
  SUM(CASE datepart(month,DateInfo) WHEN 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'March',
  SUM(CASE datepart(month,DateInfo) WHEN 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'April',
  SUM(CASE datepart(month,DateInfo) WHEN 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'May',
  SUM(CASE datepart(month,DateInfo) WHEN 6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'June',
  SUM(CASE datepart(month,DateInfo) WHEN 7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'July',
  SUM(CASE datepart(month,DateInfo) WHEN 8 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'August',
  SUM(CASE datepart(month,DateInfo) WHEN 9 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 

'September',
  SUM(CASE datepart(month,DateInfo) WHEN 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 

'October',
  SUM(CASE datepart(month,DateInfo) WHEN 11 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 

'November',
  SUM(CASE datepart(month,DateInfo) WHEN 12 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 

'December',
  SUM(CASE datepart(year,DateInfo) WHEN YEAR(GETDATE()) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 

AS 'TOTAL'

FROM
    table_emp
WHERE
   YEAR(DateInfo) = YEAR(GETDATE())

   GROUP BY Username;
```

```
+---------+----------+-------+-------+-----+------+------+--------+-----------+---------+----------+----------+-------+
| January | February | March | April | May | June | July | August | September | October | November | December | Total |
+---------+----------+-------+-------+-----+------+------+--------+-----------+---------+----------+----------+-------+
|       0 |        0 |     2 |     0 |   0 |    0 |    0 |      0 |         0 |       0 |        0 |        0 |     2 |
|       0 |        0 |     1 |     0 |   0 |    0 |    0 |      0 |         0 |       0 |        2 |        0 |     3 |
+---------+----------+-------+-------+-----+------+------+--------+-----------+---------+----------+----------+-------+
```

I am expecting the return below:

```
+---------+----------+-------+-------+-----+------+------+--------+-----------+---------+----------+----------+-------+
| January | February | March | April | May | June | July | August | September | October | November | December | Total |
+---------+----------+-------+-------+-----+------+------+--------+-----------+---------+----------+----------+-------+
|       0 |        0 |     1 |     0 |   0 |    0 |    0 |      0 |         0 |       0 |        2 |        0 |     3 |
+---------+----------+-------+-------+-----+------+------+--------+-----------+---------+----------+----------+-------+
```

Comment: Consider using PIVOT instead of all those CASE statements. It may be more difficult initially, but makes for more concise code. Check [this](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/cross-tabs-and-pivots-part-1-%e2%80%93-converting-rows-to-columns-1) out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your logic based on conditional aggregation is ok, however you should consider the following fixes:

- remove the `GROUP BY Username` clause; this will give you one record per user, which is obviously not what you want
- do not `SUM()`; instead, `COUNT(DISTINCT )` usernames per month
- I would also recommend doing explicit date comparison rather than using date functions; this allows SQL Server to take advantage of an index on `DateInfo`; this works since you are filtering on the current year.

Query:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE
        WHEN DateInfo >= '2019-01-01' AND DateInfo < '2019-02-01' 
        THEN Username 
    END) AS [January],
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE
        WHEN DateInfo >= '2019-01-02' AND DateInfo < '2019-02-03' 
        THEN Username 
    END) AS [February],
    -- repeat for other months
    COUNT(DISTINCT Username) AS [TOTAL}
FROM table_emp
WHERE DateInfo >= '2019-01-01' AND DateInfo < '2020-01-01'
```

Side note: do no use single quotes for identifiers; single quotes should be reserved for string litterals only (this is a SQL standard). Instead, use square brackets (`[]`), which is how SQL Server does it.

Comment: this appears to work out right.  I did notice that the Total would count users for every even if the user didn't have any data for a certain month.  So I modified the total to:  COUNT(DISTINCT CASE
        WHEN DateInfo >= '2019-01-01' AND DateInfo < '2020-01-01' 
        THEN Username 
    END) AS 'Total'

Comment: @Dr.Prog: I don't think that you need this, since the `WHERE` clause already filters on the year range.